# How to pass a state variable to a second view after it has been incremented in the first view in a foreach loop

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, view, state

I am really new to SwiftUI so please be gentle.  I am trying to pass the value of a state variable to a view and I want the state variable to increment inside a ForEach loop.  Here is the code that does not work.  The Text statement works fine using the local val variable but the state val variable remains unchanged.  Any help resolving this will be appreciated.  Solutions to similar issues seem not to apply.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    var val: Int = 25

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Array(stride(from: 10, to: 100, by: 10)), id: \.self) { val in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(val)")
                    SubView(val: $val)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var val: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(val)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense what you are currently doing. What are you expecting to do with the `Binding` you pass in? What will you do with it, and how will that affect `ContentView`? I fail to see what you will do with the `val` in the `@State` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are messing with the syntax of "ForEach", it is a construct that accepts a Collection as input and provides a completely custom body that is a closure that takes an element of the sequence as a parameter.

So when you call :

```
ForEach(Array(stride(from: 10, to: 100, by: 10)), id: \.self) { val in
```

You are not referring to your :

```
@State var val: Int = 25
```

You're just looping on a collection (Array(Stride)) and temporarily referring to each element with the word "val", but you cold have used any other word, for example :

```
ForEach(Array(stride(from: 10, to: 100, by: 10)), id: \.self) { increment in
```

After this premise it's clear that your "val" never change is value during the execution and it's right that both texts remain unchanged.

Another thing to understand is that the ForEach can only used for UI actions, you cannot use it for change a variable or execute code.
So I recommend that you use an alternative like the following :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    var val: Int = 25

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(val)")
            SubView(val: $val)
        }
        .onAppear {
            for i in stride(from: 10, to: 100, by: 10) {
                val = i
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't quite understand what output you want to get.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful reply.  My intent is to use the val variable to return a subview representing a row in a larger table of values to construct a table of results but I am still finding my way in SwiftUI and I make a few wrong turns!

Comment: I don't think State and Binding are your solution.
State it's like a source and Binding it's like a dynamic copy, when you change state all bindings automatically change to it's value.
So for example if you create a table with 100 rows, and each row contains a binding to val, when val is 25 all rows are equal to 25.
If you increase val, all the rows are updated to the same value.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I ended up creating a function that returned a view whose content was adjusted by the variable passed to the function that was incremented in a foreach loop.  Not sure if this is the best way but it works.